# What can be causing differing python 3.4 bytes.decode() behaviour across different installs

Tags: python, unicode

I'm seeing differing behaviour decoding a byte string on Python 3.4.3 across two boxes - one running OS X and the other Debian Wheezy.

On OS X:

```
$ python
Python 3.4.3 (default, Mar 10 2015, 14:53:35) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.56)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> s = b'\xc4\x8dtrn\xc3\xa1ct'
>>> print(s.decode("utf-8"))
čtrnáct
```

On Debian:

```
$ python
Python 3.4.3 (default, Apr  4 2015, 22:21:17) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> s = b'\xc4\x8dtrn\xc3\xa1ct'
>>> print(s.decode("utf-8"))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u010d' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

There has to be something configured slightly differently in these two installs which is causing this. I've checked the default encoding on both, and the result is identical, I'm not sure what I can check however.

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getdefaultencoding()
'utf-8'
```

update: locale returns differences between both:

OS X:

```
LANG=
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=
```

Debian:

```
$ locale
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: what does  `locale` or `echo $LANG`
output from bash?

Comment: `echo $LANG` returns nothing on OSX, and "en_US.UTF-8" on Debian. I've added the `locale` results as an edit

Comment: try  setting `LC_ALL="en_US.utf8"` if that works do `sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8`

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer - I followed the "Locales: configuration" section at http://perlgeek.de/en/article/set-up-a-clean-utf8-environment. Specifically the helpful step was:

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: It also does not mention in the article that setting LC_ALL overrides most of the others. You should also set  in `$HOME/.pam_environment` or ` `/etc/default/local`